# Install Arch Linux with wifi but wifi chipset not detected

Tags: arch-linux, broadcom

Trying to install Arch Linux on a partition of my hard drive, my only option is to connect to Internet with WiFi.

Ubuntu (on another partition) shows with `lspci` that WiFi chip-set is Broadcom **BCM4311** and `lspci -k` shows Ubuntu is using **ssb** module and **b43-pci-bridge** driver which works fine.

Arch Linux bootable USB with `lspci -k` shows that it is using the same module and driver but `ifconfig` shows no wireless interface. [Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/broadcom_wireless#b43) it is mentioned that BCM4311 works with [b43-firmware-classic](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/b43-firmware-classic/) from AUR.

Now, how can I install *b43-firmware-classic* to use my wireless chip-set, before even installing Arch Linux itself.

I ran `git clone` on Ubuntu and downloaded Arch Linux *b43-firmware-classic* from **AUR** on my Ubuntu root partition. However I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: The Ubuntu package is useless on Arch. Download the AUR tarball to a USB drive and install it from the chroot.

Comment: @jasonwryan I downloaded Arch Linux AUR package on Ubuntu, not Ubuntu package on Ubuntu.

Comment: Like I said, once you are in the chroot, install it as you would any AUR package...

Comment: @jasonwryan Right, I'm going to try.

Comment: [This](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless) Arch Wiki is written specifically for the Broadcom wifi install. Have you read through this? Download all that's needed prior to beginning install.